# Stopping animated rain in Canvas smmoothly

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Rain Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqCEc.png)So my issue isn't stopping the rain its stopping the making of the rain so the already rendered rain completes its animation off the screen.

I tried setInterval and setTimeout in JS but it just freezes.

And using JQuery to remove canvas tag takes off all drops at once.

Any ideas or direction would be great!

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("rainCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasW = window.innerWidth;
    var canvasH = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.height = canvasH;
    canvas.width = canvasW;


var mf = 70;
var drops = [];



for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
    drops.push({
        x: Math.random()*canvasW,
        y: Math.random()*canvasH,
        r: Math.random()*5+2,
        d: Math.random() + 1
    })

}

function fill() {
    ctx.fill();
    }



function drawRain(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
        var f = drops[i];
        ctx.moveTo(f.x-5, f.y);
        ctx.lineTo(f.x, f.y-15);
        ctx.lineTo(f.x+5, f.y);
        ctx.arc(f.x, f.y + f.r*.7,5, 0, Math.PI, false);
    }
    fill();

    moveRain();

}

function moveRain(){
    for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
        var f = drops[i];
        f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;

        if(f.y > canvasH){
            drops[i] = {x: Math.random()*canvasW, y: 0, r: f.r, d: f.d};
        }
    }
}


var i = setInterval(drawRain, 20);


setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(); }, 2000);
```

```css
canvas{ background-color: black }
```

```html
<canvas id="rainCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example? you can use snippets or jsfiddle.net for that

Comment: *but it just freezes* so it snows?

Comment: Add added a link with a still picture...thats all I got for now

Comment: @angelHank I added the extra items to you code and made it into a  snippet.

Comment: thanks @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: *so the already rendered rain completes its animation **off the screen*** <-- could you elaborate?

Comment: just pointing out that `setInterval` is generally the wrong approach when it comes to (full-page) animations. A good alternative would be `setAnimationFrame` which shuts itself down after the last drop of rain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is set a flag to stop the rain from wrapping back to the top in your function to stop raining:

```
var stopRain = false;

...

setTimeout(function( ) { stopRain = true; }, 2000);
```

Now inside `moveRain` when that variable is `true` instead of moving it back to the top remove it from the array. Once we removed all the drops we can then clear the interval as it's no longer needed:

```
function moveRain(){
    for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
        var f = drops[i];
        f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;

        if(f.y > canvasH){
            if(stopRain) {              // When we stop raining 
            drops.splice(i, 1);        // Remove drop from array
            mf--;                      // Make sure to update the "length"
            if(mf<1) clearInterval(i); // If there are not more drops clear the interval
          } else drops[i] = {x: Math.random()*canvasW, y: 0, r: f.r, d: f.d};
        }
    }
}
```

[***Fiddle Example***](https://jsfiddle.net/jvqtamfq/)

You could also use `drops.length` instead of using `mf`, this way you don't need to do `mf--`.

Comment: You are awesome .

Answer (score 0):

Here I fixed some of the code and added a `rainDensity` variable which controls the count of new raindrops. The original code was designed to have a fixed amount of raindrops, it had to be changed to achieve the desired effect.

```js
window.onload = function(){

  var canvas = document.getElementById("rainCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var canvasW = window.innerWidth;
  var canvasH = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.height = canvasH;
  canvas.width = canvasW;

  var drops = [];
  
  function makeDrop() {
    drops.push({
      x: Math.random()*canvasW,
      y: -10,
      r: Math.random()*4+1,
      d: Math.pow(Math.random() + 1, 2) + 1
    })
  }


  function drawRain(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128, 128, 255, .5)";
    for(var f of drops){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(f.x-5, f.y);
      ctx.lineTo(f.x, f.y-15);
      ctx.lineTo(f.x+5, f.y);
      ctx.arc(f.x, f.y + f.r*.7,5, 0, Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  
  function handleFrame() {
    drawRain();
    updateRain();
  }
  
  function updateRain() {
    moveRain();
    makeNewDrops();
  }

  var dropPerFrameCounter = 0;
  var startTime = Date.now();
  function makeNewDrops() {
    var elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;  
    // rainDensity: set it to 0 to stop rain
    var rainDensity = Math.max(0, Math.sin(elapsedTime / 3) + 0.5);
    dropPerFrameCounter += rainDensity;
    while (dropPerFrameCounter >= 1) {
      dropPerFrameCounter--;
      makeDrop();
    }
  }
  function moveRain() {
    for(var f of drops){
      f.y += f.d;
    }
    drops = drops.filter(d => d.y < canvasH);
  }

  var intervalRender = setInterval(handleFrame, 20);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="rainCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to add an answer because the example all used  `setInterval` to do the animation which looks awful. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate. Also fixed some other problems with the code.

I have added a pause the pauses the animation when you click on the canvas. Clicking again will continue.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("rainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasW = window.innerWidth;
var canvasH = window.innerHeight;
canvas.height = canvasH;
canvas.width = canvasW;
var mf = 70;
var drops = [];
var paused = false;



for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
    drops.push({
        x: Math.random()*canvasW,
        y: Math.random()*canvasH,
        r: Math.random()*5+2,
        d: Math.random() + 1
    })

}




function drawRain(){
    if(!paused){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasW, canvasH);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
            var f = drops[i];
            ctx.moveTo(f.x - 2.5 * f.d, f.y);
            ctx.lineTo(f.x, f.y - 7.5 * f.d);
            ctx.lineTo(f.x + 2.5 * f.d, f.y);
            ctx.arc(f.x, f.y + f.r * 0.7, 2.5 * f.d, 0, Math.PI, false);
        }
        ctx.fill();

       for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
            var f = drops[i];
            f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;

            if(f.y > canvasH + 15){ // make sure completely off the bottom
               // dont create a new drop reuse it will stop GC from 
               // having to interrupt the code.
                f.x =  Math.random()*canvasW;
                f.y = -6; // move off top
                
            }
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawRain);
}


requestAnimationFrame(drawRain);
canvas.addEventListener("click",()=>{paused = ! paused});
```

```css
canvas{
   background-color: black;
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="rainCanvas"></canvas>
```